# Link to chat from Site Switcher is not HTTPS

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, ssl

On the Site Switcher drop down

[image]

The link to chat is not https.  Inspecting the element gives me

```
<div class="related-links">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:14 })">help</a>
    <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })">chat</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:8 })">log out</a>
</div>
```

Is there are reason chat is not marked as HTTPS when chat is running on HTTPS?

[image]

Comment: Chat is formally still on the https to-do list.

Comment: [The "Chat" section](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#chat) on the [`https` migration blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/)

Answer (score 5):

This look to be fixed since at least this morning.  The links in the Site Switcher are now

```
<div class="related-links">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:14 })">help</a>
    <a href="https://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })">chat</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:8 })">log out</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep - I'm working on chat as time allows right now (we've got some other fires with monitoring+storage I have to hop on tomorrow, then back to it).

Comment: Awesome @NickCraver.  Thanks for letting me know.